# Set EdgeList of adjacency_list graph explicitly from a storage container

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have a program in which I need to repeatedly destroy and restore a graph.  I have declared it as

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::hash_mapS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperties> Graph;
```

What I would like to do is to copy the EdgeOutList `hash_map` to a separate variable and then copy it back in to restore it.  I've been using `copy_graph` with the full graph but it has to reallocate everything that way, I'd prefer to just copy the edge_list to the original object.

There does not seem to be any documentation for this sort of procedure, though I may have not understood something.